# Update player list on all clients on new connection

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am trying to make a small multiplayer game. I got everything to work, the server accepts multiple connections and keeps track of everything that is connected. The local game client has its own player which it controls with A for left and D for right.

Whenever I start the [**server**] then connect [**client 1**] to it, it all works fine. The server keeps track of a list of players and sends it to the clients whenever a new one connects. So that all the players are drawn on every client.

However, when I connect to the same [**server**] with [**client 2**], it does what it's supposed to do and draws both the players on the screen of [**client 2**] . But it does not draw the second player on [**client 1**] even though the player list was sent to every client, [**client 1**] & [**client 2**].

When I connect a third client it does the same thing as above but only [**client 3**] loads all 3 players.

I've tried several ways of programming this but could not get it to work. What am I doing wrong? My code is open-source on github: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/mbootsgezel/Network-MMO)

I really appreciate the help!